# selectlist distinct upper mix in query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

i am using asp.net mvc4. in my controller i am trying to use linq to select distinct countries, however, since users are inputting the countries with their address, i can't control the format.
so in my query i would like to avoid duplicate entries from my drop down. i could do this easily in sql query, well linq is a whole different story.

so below is my linq:

```
 ViewBag.country = new SelectList(db.SchoolReports.OrderBy(o => o.country), "country", "country").Distinct().ToList();
```

the only problem with the above is this, stil duplicates!:

```
Australia
australia
AusTralia
```

any ideas? how can i use UPPER with linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you Linq call `Distinct` like this:

```
Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
```

Instead of using a standard string compare this will use one that ignores the case of the text.